# How to find the number and summation of samples of a random variable, before its value exceeds a threshold?

Tags: random-variables

Assume there are a set of nodes lie on a line, and the space between each pair of neighboring nodes follows the Log-normal distribution.

Those nodes are able to communicate with their neighbor, if the distance between them is shorter than a threshold. So the sets of nodes who are able to communicate formulates many "clusters".

It is possible to find the mathematical expression of: 1. the size (or expected size), and 2. the length (or expected length) of these clusters?

Thank you!